# Проверить, открыт ли stream (TCP)

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, tcp

```
public NetworkStream stream;
```

У меня в цикле прослушивается поток на чтение. Но при определённом условии я его закрываю:

```
stream.Close();
```

Цикл при этом не останавливается, и когда в следующей итерации пытаюсь прослушать поток:

```
stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Возникает исключение, так как поток закрыт.
Скажите, пожалуйста, как я могу делать проверку на открытость данного потока?

```
if (ПОТОК ОТКРЫТ)
{
    stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Comment: `.Socket.Connected`, а еще `.Readable` и `.Writeable` вам в помощь.

Comment: if (stream.Connected) - приводит к ошибке  'NetworkStream' does not contain a definition for 'Connected' and no accessible extension method 'Connected' accepting a first argument of type 'NetworkStream' could be found

Comment: Внимательно еще раз прочитайте мой первый коммент, я указал там `.Connected` или всеж `.Socket.Connected`? Ну а вообще, советую зайти в документацию класса и посмотреть что в нем есть.

Comment: @InquisErnesto когда вы создаёте NetworkStream, для создания вы используете Socket, проверяйте его свойство Connected. Хотя Connected не самый надёжный индикатор, и может давать ложно-положительное состояние, можете ещё использовать Socket.Poll(), но он уже может давать ложно-отрицательные состояния при минимальных задержках сверх ожидаемых.